# Binary Image ROI Tracking opencv

Tags: opencv, tracking, matching, head

I seem to be stuck in a particular problem where I want to track a region of a Binary Image in the next frames. The region goes through motion (rotation and translation). I have isolated this block and wondering what are the options.

I have considered correlation/template/SSD,also optical flow, the farneback method.

For your information, the human head motion is tracked in successive frames.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So the goal is to track human head motion in terms of rotation and translation over time?

Comment: So, a bounding box is placed around the human head in 2D binary image, the goal is to find out the best match for the location of the head in the next frame, yes head goes through rotation/translation.

Comment: Binary Image is challenging are you not able to get a 8bit gray valued image. Optical Flow (Farneback) should not work on this data, as they are based on spatio-temporal gradients.